# Installing plugins from npm causes errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic2

I'm working on Visual Studio 2017 using Ionic v2, I'm trying to write an app that scan beacons. But everytime I install a plugin I get errors from the npm regarding the versions of node and npm itself.
My current versions:

```
Cordova version: 7.0.1
Npm version: 5.0.3
Node version: 8.1.3
```

For example I installed cordova bluetoothle plugin and that's the error I get:

```
    npm ERR! node v5.4.1
    npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! io.cordova.myappd95ddb@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the io.cordova.myappd95ddb@ build script 'ionic-app-
             scripts build'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the io.cordova.myappd95ddb 
             package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

I looked on the internet but apparently there aren't many update plugins that work with bluetooth, does that mean I necessarily need to downgrade my node and npm version?
Do you know any other plugin I could use?

npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Web\\External\\Node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
 Studio\\2017\\Community\\Web\\External\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build',
1 verbose cli   '--color=always' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.4
3 info using node@v5.4.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~prebuild: io.cordova.myappd95ddb@
6 silly lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
7 info lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~build: io.cordova.myappd95ddb@
8 verbose lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~build: PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\giuli\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\test\test\node_modules\.bin;.\node_modules\.bin;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\Web\External;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\giuli\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\giuli\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs
10 verbose lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~build: CWD: C:\Users\giuli\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\test\test
11 silly lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ionic-app-scripts build' ]
12 silly lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle io.cordova.myappd95ddb@~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: io.cordova.myappd95ddb@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:233:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid io.cordova.myappd95ddb@
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\giuli\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\test\test
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Web\\External\\Node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Web\\External\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build" "--color=always"
19 error node v5.4.1
20 error npm  v3.3.4
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error io.cordova.myappd95ddb@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the io.cordova.myappd95ddb@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
23 error This is most likely a problem with the io.cordova.myappd95ddb package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     ionic-app-scripts build
23 error You can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls io.cordova.myappd95ddb
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved like this: In Vs open Tools/Options/Project and Solution/ External Web Package. Move $PATH on top of ../external.